# Why do i get a file named history in each folder in bash?

Tags: macos, bash, gnu-screen, history

For some reason I get a bash history file in each and every folder where I issue any command. The file is called history rather than the normal .bash_history.

My .bash_profile has the following that affects history.

```
45 shopt -s histappend
46 PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND history -a"
```

I'm using GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release installed on Mac via Homebrew.

[edit]
I just noticed that I only get the file when running in screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing a semicolon, try changing it to this
`PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; $PROMPT_COMMAND"`